# viewController added to UIScrollView not calling its viewDidAppear method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, ipad

I have a UIScrollView which has 2 different views added via **viewController1.view** and **viewController2.view** properties. I want to be notified when **viewController1.view** or **viewController2.view** has appeared on screen. Tried to use the **viewDidAppear** method but it does not gets called.

Missed something? Any ideas?

Thanks!

```
//Add xViewController to scrollView
[scrollView addSubview:firstViewController.view];
[scrollView addSubview:secondViewController.view];
[scrollView addSubview:thirdViewController.view];
[scrollView addSubview:fourthViewController.view];
```

Comment: please post the code where you add the viewController1.view to the scrollview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methods such as viewDidAppear can only be fired when view controllers are pushed to the stack, not singular views. Sorry I can't really advise on how else you could track getting them to the screen - unless you initialised and hide their contents, then once this was ready you'd know you were just one .hidden = NO call away from showing them.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use contentOffset of the scrollview to calculate which view is being displayed in the UIScrollViewDelegate function scrollViewDidScroll.

Look at the implementation of PageControl to understand how UIScrollView works.[PageControl Demo](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html)